# ASP.NET MVC Core - Extending model binder to handle empty lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The default behavior for model binder is to return null for enumerable properties if the request contains empty array. I would like to return an empty collection instead. For other properties I want to retain default behavior.

I'm migrating from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET MVC Core. In the old project, I had a custom model binder extending DefaultModelBinder. However, DefaultModelBinder does not exist in Core.

```
public class EmptyListModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var model = base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);

        if (model == null || model is IEnumerable)
            return model;

        foreach (var property in modelType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(model);
            if (value != null)
               continue;

            if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                value = Array.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType.GetElementType(), 0);
                property.SetValue(model, value);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                Type typeToCreate;
                Type genericTypeDefinition = property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genericTypeDefinition == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
                {
                    typeToCreate = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments());
                }
                else if (genericTypeDefinition == typeof(IEnumerable<>) ||
                     genericTypeDefinition == typeof(ICollection<>) ||
                     genericTypeDefinition == typeof(IList<>) ||
                     genericTypeDefinition == typeof(List<>))
                {
                    typeToCreate = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments());
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }

                value = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToCreate);
                property.SetValue(model, value);
            }
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

I could extend ComplexTypeModelBinder, but it's deprecated. It's replaced by ComplexObjectModelBinder, which is sealed and cannot be inherited or used for composition.

How could I achieve this behavior in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: It's better to add snippests for your requirement for understand clearly.

Comment: I believe that if you just initialize the property to an empty collection, it will work. The model should be first created using parameterless constructor (even if not explicitly written) - that creates an empty collection and than model binder is applied - that will fill the collection if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net core provides custom model binding, which is inherited from IModelBinder.

> 1. Implement the Binder Class

```
public class CustomBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly NewDemoContext _context;

    public CustomBinder(NewDemoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        // Check if the argument value is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            var temp = new List<string>{};
            var model0 = new CustomModelBinder()
            {
                CMBCode = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("CMBCode").ToString(),
                CMBListFirst = temp,
                CMBListSecond = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("CMBListSecond").ToList(),
            };
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model0);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        //remain
        var model = new CustomModelBinder() { };
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

> 2. The BinderProvider

```
public class CustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(CustomModelBinder))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(CustomBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

> 3. Add the binder property on the model or on your action

```
The model
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomBinder))]
public class CustomModelBinder
{
    public int CMBid { get; set; }
    public string? CMBCode { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<string>? CMBListFirst { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<string>? CMBListSecond { get; set; }
}

The action
public IActionResult Bding([ModelBinder(Name = "CMBFirstList")]CustomModelBinder model)
{
    return View();
}
```

> 4. Add the service

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
});
```

Test:

> My url:
> https://localhost:7046/custommodelbinder/Bding?CMBid=0&CMBCode=test@test.com&CMBListFirst=&CMBListSecond=["22","33"]
> //ListFirst is null

[image]

List Value is null

[image]

Model passed to action

[image]

Pages

For more details, check the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-model-binder-sample